# How to connect in PHP to a MySQL database without getting errors due to cPanel?

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel, mysqlnd

This basic commands:

```
new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
```

are blocked in PHP 8.2+ with `Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found` or `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()` (depends on which one you used) seemingly due to [PHP 8.2: MySQLi can no longer be compiled with libmysqli](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mysqli-libmysql-no-longer-supported) (which suggests to use the `mysqlnd` library instead of the `libmysql` library).

The way to bypass it in cPanel, [as explained here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/which-php-extensions-is-recommended-nd_mysqli-nd_pdo_mysql-or-mysqli/) (and in a past version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46936899/4829915)), is to check the usually turned off `nd_mysqli`, since obviously having `mysqlnd` (which is checked by default) is not enough.

But since my hosting explained *"the reason why the "nd_mysqli" was disabled is because the module is **not** recommended"*, is there another PHP command that **is** recommended for PHP 8.2+ to connect to a MySQL database from PHP that will not trigger any errors or require any special setup?

[image: MySQL in cPanel]

Comment: You mean like, apart from PDO?

Comment: Have you read what PHP offers you? [Overview of the MySQL PHP drivers - Choosing an API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: This link compares between mysqli and PDO. I believe it's likely PDO will trigger a similar error unless you enable `nd_pdo_mysql`, which again means enabling a non recommended option, @Félix Adriyel Gagnon-Grenier and @maio290.

Comment: I use PDO with php 8.2 currently. The article you share is explicitly about mysqli.

Comment: True. I've just tried it and `new PDO` works even without `nd_pdo_mysql`. So are you saying one should choose PDO over mysqli simply over the lack of need to enable a non default extension? This advantage isn't even mentioned in the comparison. In fact, the only benefit there to PDO is client-side Prepared Statements, while listing several disadvantages.

Comment: I'm just used to PDO, is all. I er... really do not think that the problem you observe is linked to your article however. What the article says, is that one can no longer compile php with libmysql, but if your host did compile it *they assuredly did so using mysqlnd*, if libmysql is no longer available. I do not believe that php 8.2 doesn't ship with mysqli anymore, unless someone messed up things greatly. Are you certain you in fact enabled the mysqli extension?

Comment: `nd_mysqli` is disabled by default. Once I enable it, the errors of lack of mysqli immediately go away and the db connection works. Once I disable `nd_mysqli` again, the errors immediately return.

Comment: Right. I think I start to see clearly. I'm still confused by 1. why is there no mysqli extension box in your cpanel. I can see one in mine (along the nd_mysqli one). 2. Who's doing that non-recommendation anyway? 3. how come you would be presented with no way to continue using mysqli. I would start looking for a new host before rewriting away from mysqli, a host must offer a way for people to use mysqli with php 8.2.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow let's move this to a chat if you like. 1. The "as explained here" link in the OP suggests it's a known scenario. 2. I do it because that's the way to continue using mysqli. 3. The host does let me enable `nd_mysqli` which fixes everything - they said they can't recommend it but stated it's my choice.

Comment: sure, you can ping me in the [php chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) if you want. if I don't answer there's a lot of very knowledgeable people around anyway (that may or may not be interested in this question, so navigate accordingly)

Comment: This has nothing to do with how anything was built / compiled. If the classes / functions aren't available, then the associated extension has not been enabled. Simple as that

Comment: But given that mysqli is quite a standard, i just wonder why would it be turned off by default.

Comment: @LWC That is simply how it works. Php comes with many extensions compiled in, but none are enabled. Developers can then choose which ones they need. Why would mysqli be enabled over pdo, for instance? The only real problem here, is why does your host not provide a valid mysqli (not nd_mysqli) extension with the php executable. that's super weird. I'd push back really hard on that. it's not acceptable. A php installation has a mysqli extension that can be enabled, otherwise it's not php, it's some dastardly corruption.

Comment: But that's exactly it - PDO works out of the box. Regarding the host, what does enabling `nd_mysqli` not count as providing a valid mysqli extension?

Comment: ask them. they're the one compiling the software they make available on your server. all we're saying is that if mysqli functions are not available, it's because the extension is not enabled. if your host does not provide a mysqli extension you can use, that's extremely concerning.

Comment: do come hang out in the php chat @LWC, I feel we've reached, and possibly went over, the generally accepted limit of comments ;-)

Comment: I did ask them. Judging from their answers it just comes this way. They just suggest to enable `nd_mysqli` which fixes everything despite the risk of enabling non default extensions.

Comment: anyway. last thing I'll say here @LWC is: a host must offer a way they recommend of using mysqli. this is not arguable. Either they offer a php installation that works, that means has a mysqli (or nd_mysqli) extension they support, or they do not in fact offer php, they offer a custom thing that looks like php. by the way, I cannot find anything to the effect that nd_mysqli is not recommended, it looks like it's simply the name given to mysqli by cpanel hosters. I really doubt the person who told you "that's not recommended" has any clue what they're saying.

Comment: That person just said they can't recommend anything that isn't a default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254078/discussion-between-felix-adriyel-gagnon-grenier-and-lwc).

Answer (score 0):

The recommended extension has always been PDO. However, if your site is already written using mysqli, you can continue using it even on PHP 8.2.

CPanel is stupid and their idiotic configuration has confused a lot of people. They compiled both PDO and mysqli with libmysql by default and only offered the better mysqlnd variant as a non-standard extension with prefix nd_. Users should never use the libmysql variants and on PHP 8.2 it's no longer possible to even offer mysqli with that library. The correct extensions that should always be enabled are:

- nd_pdo_mysql
- nd_mysqli

I don't know what they offer under the name mysqlnd as it's not an extension that can be enabled or disabled. Offering this as an option in configuration is ridiculous.

I can't understand a reason why cPanel would not recommend the nd_* variants.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/73902084/1839439

Comment: Can you source that PDO is recommended over mysqli? Also, how come PDO works even without nd_pdo_mysql?

Comment: @lwc PDO can still be compiled against the libmysql library.  So cPanel still offers both variants.